# Curve generated from Outline tool using Curve Tools does not show in object mode

Tags: 3d-view, add-on, bezier-curves

I used Curve Tools to make an offset duplicate of a NURBS curve in *Edit Mode*, which worked fine, however the offset curve does not have any geometry and does not show in object mode.

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Enable *Curve Tools* (Add Curve: Curve Tools)
2. Add any curve
3. Enter *Edit Mode*, select *Edit* in sidebar
4. Then use *Outline* in *Curve Edit*

[image: Edit mode]

[image: Object mode]

Blender Version 3.5.1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the *Outline* function in the *Curve Edit* tools is, it does not create a proper *NURBS* curve, and simply setting the curve to *NURBS* does not function as expected.

So in order to make a working *NURBS* curve from the outline you have to do the following:

1. Select a control point of the outline curve and in the *Curve* menu choose *Set Spline Type* > *Poly*.

   [image: spline type poly]
2. After that, go to the *Curve* menu again and choose *Set Spline Type* > *NURBS*.

   [image: spline type nurbs]
3. To have the same settings as on the original curve, go to the curve's *Object Data Properties* and under *Active Spline* check *Endpoint*.

   [image: enable endpoint]

But due to the fact how *NURBS* curves are calculated, the resulting curve is no longer an outline of the original curve. This is not an error in the outline tool, it's just the way they work:

[image: new nurbs curve]

Probably you would be better off doing this with a *Bézier Curve* instead of a *NURBS Curve* and then using the *Recursive Offset* tool (this will create a new curve object which you could of course join with the original), just make sure you set the *Resolution* to a small angle to get a smooth curve:

[image: recursive offset]

The *Recursive Offset* has more options than the *Outline* tool like creating multiple offset lines by a given *Count* number with a specific distance between each other given by the *Pitch* value:

[image: pitch and count]